# problems waking ubuntu 20.04.3 from sleep hbm: pg entry_response: state mismatch [OFF, 0]

Tags: suspend, wakeup

Whenever I try to wake my Acer laptop one of two things happen; either I get a blank screen with a blinking cursor, or I'll get two errors that say:

```
[   577.337847] mei_me 0000:00:16.0 hbm: pg entry response: state mismatch [OFF, 0]
[   577.337901] mei_me 0000:00:16.0 me_irq_read_handler ret = -71.
```

Any thoughts on what it means and how to fix it?

Thanks